# React Router and browser back button

Tags: reactjs, browser, react-router, back

I have a Router Switch that includes these Routes:

```
<Route exact path={['/', '/gg/']}><Spinner /></Route>
<Route path={['/error', '/gg/error']} render={() => <Error />} />
```

The app loads via '.../gg/' and during this spinner it makes axios calls to the database. If the call response is an error, the error component is loaded via '.../error'.

My problem is this - after the error page loads, when I click the browser back button it goes back to '.../gg' rather than the page before loading this app. I want it to go back to the page before '.../gg' and not load /gg at all. But I don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a Redirect component from react-router-dom. Set a redirect state as false, then if the database returns an error, you set redirect state to true.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
// (...)

function Component(){
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  // your fetch that set redirect to true in case of error

  if (redirect) return <Redirect to='/gg/error' />;

  return (<div>Component</div>);
}
```